# ArcGIS Pro Python Validate and Alter Field Names

Tags: arcpy, python, fields-attributes, data-management

I want to check if the field names in shapefile start with a number (or other forbidden character) or if they contain spaces. If so I want to update the names into some which are correct.

I tried:

```
Fields = ['abc', '0-9 abc' ]
list_len = range(len(Fields))
        for i in list_len:
            arcpy.AlterField_management(FromPolygon, Fields[i], arcpy.ValidateFieldName(Fields[i]))
```

But I get an error message:

> Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
>   ERROR 000664: Invalid input: The type of dataset is not supported.
>   Failed to execute (AlterField).

`Fields` is a list of strings.

Comment: The [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/alter-field-properties.htm) states *This tool provides the ability to rename fields or field aliases for any geodatabase table or feature class.* Combined with a `The type of dataset is not supported` error, I'd guess that shapefiles aren't supported.

Comment: Is there a similar tool for shapefiels or do I need to delete old (with wrong names) and add new ones?

Comment: Copy/export shape to file geodatabase, Alter Field, Copy/export as shape. Or use MakeFeatureLayer (renaming the fields) - Copy features